# ¿Hay una mejor traducción para up-vote y down-vote que voto positivo y voto negativo?

Tags: traducción, solicitud-de-término, vocabulario-técnico, informática

En Stack Overflow y la red Stack Exchange, existe el concepto de *upvote* y *downvote*, que todos usamos diariamente para calificar las preguntas y respuestas que encontramos en los sitios de la red.

No me ha resultado fácil expresar esto en español, cuándo he realizado la traducción de las [preguntas frecuentes de Area51](http://jachguate.wordpress.com/stackoverflow-en-espanol/area51-preguntas-frecuentes-faq/) hace algunas semanas, y por tanto he dejado:

- *upvote*: votar positivamente o voto positivo
- *downovote*: votar negativamente o voto negativo

Dado que ahora he encontrado este sitio, me gustaría saber si alguien en la comunidad tiene una mejor palabra o expresión en español para expresar el concepto.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Pues, yo optaría por:

- **Votar a favor**.
- **Votar en contra**.

Creo que son expresiones más naturales, *al menos en España*.

Comment: En Menéame (con una grandísima mayoría de usuarios españoles) se usa positivo y negativo, porque suma o resta karma. Además, se parece a los puntos positivos y negativos del colegio.

Comment: @JoulSauron, en mi opinión, el hecho de que supe o reste _karma_ o _reputación_ es secundario pues, tomando la respuesta, uno vota a favor o en contra del contenido, y si, esta me parece una respuesta bastante acertada y a falta de otras, la aceptada también.

Comment: @jachguate Como alternativa, que es lo que preguntabas, sí, la respuesta es perfecta.

Comment: Lamentablemente, en español no hay una traducción directa de una sola palabra, ya que en inglés muchos términos pueden terminar usándose como verbos y en español esto no ocurre tan seguido. Me parece natural la opción que das.

Answer (score 2):

Aunque ya se ha expresado como comentado en otra respuesta, creo conveniente plasmarlo en una respuesta aparte.

Las palabras ***positivo*** y ***negativo*** se pueden usar como sustantivos. De hecho, buscando una respuesta a una duda en Stack Overflow acabo de conseguir hacer una cosa que quería, y me ha salido solo:

> ¡Te mereces un positivo!

Creo que son opciones más cortas que "voto a favor" o "en contra".

Answer (score 1):

> Más   y   Menos
>
> Aprueba  y Critica
>
> Elogia   y  Dale Caña